# Is division axiomatizable?

Tags: model-theory

Consider a set $G$ with a group operation. We can define a division operation $a*(b^{-1})$ and call it $\operatorname{div}$. Is the class of division operations first order axiomatizable? And if so, is it finitely axiomatizable?

Comment: Not only is it axiomatizable, but you can make it the only operation on a group. If $a\star b = ab^{-1}$ then $1\star b=b^{-1}$ and $ab=a\star(1\star b)$. So you can axiomatize groups with the constant $1$ and the single operation $\star$. I would hesitate to call it "division," since we talk about "division" in the integers, as well, and you'd have to distinguish left and right division. In abelian groups, we'd even often call it "subtraction" rather than division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\star$ be your operator. On a group, this can be axiomatized as:

$$\forall x(1\star(1\star x)=x)\text{ (A)}\\ \forall x(x\star x = 1)\text{ (B)}\\\forall x,y,z\left((x\star y)\star z = x\star(z\star(1\star y))\right)\text{ (C)}$$

We can quickly show:

$$\begin{align}
x\star 1 &= (1\star(1\star x))\star 1 \text{ (A)}\\
&=1\star(1\star(1\star(1\star x)))\text{ (C)}\\
&=1\star(1\star x)\text{ (A)}\\
&=x\text{ (A)}
\end{align}
$$
Then if you define $x^{-1}=1\star x$ and $x\cdot y = x\star(1\star y)$, we can show:

$$x\cdot x^{-1} = x\star(1\star(1\star x)) = x\star x = 1\\
x^{-1}\cdot x = (1\star x)\star (1\star x)=1\\
1\cdot x = 1\star(1\star x)=x\\
x\cdot 1 = x\star (1\star 1) = x\star 1 = 1\\
\begin{align}(x\cdot y)\cdot z&=(x\star(1\star y))\star(1\star z)\\
&=x\star\left((1\star z)\star(1\star(1\star y))\right)\\
&=x\star\left((1\star z)\star y\right)\\
&=x\star(1\star (y\star(1\star z)))\\
&= x\cdot(y\cdot z)
\end{align}
$$
and finally:

$$a\cdot b^{-1} = a\star(1\star(1\star b)) = a\star b$$

So you've got all your group axioms.

Comment: You can also define $1$ by your second axiom if you have instead an axiom $(\forall x\forall y) x\star x= y\star y$. Then you only need $\star$ in the signature.